# Unknown provider: $cordovaSQLiteProvider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have installed sqlite cordova plugin using this instruction as following :
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Please look at following controller code :

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $scope.playlists = [
      { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
      { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
      { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
      { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
      { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
      { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
    ];

    //var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });

    //// for opening a background db:
    //var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", bgType: 1 });

    //$scope.execute = function () {
    //    var query = "INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)";
    //    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test", 100]).then(function (res) {
    //        console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
    //    }, function (err) {
    //        console.error(err);
    //    });
    //};

})
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: Did you inject ngCordova? e.g. `angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])`

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue! I have referred https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the error by referring this link : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

step-1 : Download this : [Link](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/archive/master.zip)  and copy ng-cordova.min.js into your "www/js" directory.

step-2 : use this command to in cmd

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
```

step-3 : Open your index.html file and add the following line:

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

It is very important you add it above the cordova.js line otherwise it will not work.

step-4 : One more thing must be added before we can start using ngCordova.  We need to inject it into our angular.module, found in app.js, like the following:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

That's it. Now sqlite is usable.